# Firebase push notifications not working on production apk

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin

Trying to use Firebase to send notifications to the Android app, everything works well when sending apk to the phone via USB. When I archive and distribute AdHoc, notifications are not working.
My code:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do the following

1) plug in your phone to your PC with USB cable
2) VS Menu -> Tools -> Android -> Android ADB command prompt
adb shell 
logcat | grep AppName
(the AppName is the name that is found in VS Menu -> Project -> Appname Properties ->Android Manifest ->Package name
3) Run you notification
4) Get the output from the crash and post it here.

Comment: there is no output when i run notification.

Comment: You above code is Ok, can you share a demo with AdHoc?